# ExpressJS Handlebars update partials when file change

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I register partial like this.

```
Handlebars.registerPartial({
  'top': fs.readFileSync('./views/partials/top.handlebars','utf8'),
});
```

But when I change the file top.handlebars the system remain the old version until I restart server.

Is there anyway to upload partials content. without manually restart Nodejs server?

Comment: How are you running your server? For development, you may want to use something like [`nodemon`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) to restart your server for you when you make changes to your files.

Comment: runing server: PM2. development not a problem

Comment: Are you using [express-handlebars](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars)